# scale_color_manual not working for assigning custermized color

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-plotly, scale-color-manual

I am working on assigning the same action code with a specific color but the  scale_color_manual  does not works for me. The color picked up is still by default. Any suggestions? That will be really helpful!! Either assign the action code using the color column or picked color like 'red'/'black'

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(stringr)
    library(librudate)
    category <- c('task1', 'task2', 'task2','task1','task1')
    start_min <- c(0,   0,  16,   20,   40)
    stop_min <- c(14.9,10, 30, 35, 70)
    color <- c('#FFFF00','#FFFF00','#3581B8','#3581B8', '#FFFFFF')
    action <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C')
    data <- data.frame(category,start_min,stop_min, color)
    
    bars <- ggplot(data, mapping=aes(ymin=0, ymax=2,
                                                  xmin=start_min, xmax=stop_min,
                                                  group=category,
                                                  fill=action,
                                                  text=paste("Task:", str_wrap(string = action, width = 70,),
                                                            
                                                             "<br>category: ", format(category, digits=1), 
                                                             "<br>Duration: ", format(action, digits=1)) 
    )) + 
      facet_grid(category ~ .)+
      geom_rect(alpha=0.8) +
      labs(title='System Tag') +
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, color="white"), #legend.position = 'none',
            plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=1, vjust=1, color="white"),
            axis.title.x=element_text(color="white"), axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
      scale_color_manual(
                         breaks = c("A", "B", "C"),
                         values = c("A" = "blue", "B" = "red", "C" = "black") )
    
    
    bars <- plotly::ggplotly(bars, tooltip="text") %>%
      plotly::ggplotly(bars, tooltip="text") %>%
      plotly::config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
      plotly::layout(plot_bgcolor='white', paper_bgcolor='white', margin = list(b=30, l=0, r=10, t=30))
    
    bars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the fix is very easy, change `scale_color_manual` to `scale_fill_manual`

If you want colors to be the color in your `color` variable, just do this:

```r
scale_fill_manual(
        breaks = c("A", "B", "C"),
        values = color)
```